# Custom List schema.xml with custom content type - attribute code duplication

Tags: content-type, custom-list, site-column, custom-schema

I made a custom content type with several custom site columns, all defined in a Elements.xml

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Customer -->
  <Field
       ID="{8A907E22-C36D-43C0-B541-6B8F8FBFBC0F}"
       Name="Customer"
       DisplayName="$Resources:CuVi,sc_customer;"
       Required="TRUE"
       Type="Text"
       Group="Customer Visitor Site Columns">
  </Field>
  <!-- Brand -->
  <Field
       ID="{9c535734-2c4f-4259-8871-32ed72236731}"
       Name="Brand"
       DisplayName="$Resources:CuVi,sc_brand;"
       Required="TRUE"
       Type="Note"
       RichText="False"
       NumLines="4"
       Group="Customer Visitor Site Columns">
  </Field>
  <!-- Contact -->
  <Field
       ID="{305ce425-9875-4604-8afc-39d79b779e72}"
       Name="ContactPeople"
       DisplayName="$Resources:CuVi,sc_contactpeople;"
       BaseType="Text"
       Type="UserMulti" Sealed="TRUE"
       List="UserInfo"
       UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"
       Group="Customer Visitor Site Columns">
  </Field> 
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Item (0x01) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x0100636C625E34BA404AB3F7CA5DC0E9C9F2" Name="$Resources:CuVi,ct_customervisitor_title;" Group="Custom Content Types" Description="$Resources:CuVi,ct_customervisitor_desc;" Inherits="FALSE" Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{8A907E22-C36D-43C0-B541-6B8F8FBFBC0F}" Required="TRUE" />      
      <FieldRef ID="{9c535734-2c4f-4259-8871-32ed72236731}" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{305ce425-9875-4604-8afc-39d79b779e72}" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE" />    
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Now I want to deploy a list instance using this custom content type.
With adding the content type in user interface, Visual Studio generates a schema.xml, but all attributes of my content type has been defined in the schema.xml too. So I have massive code duplication.

```
<List
    xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="CustomerVisitorsList" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/CustomerVisitorsList" BaseType="0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" EnableContentTypes="TRUE">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x0100636C625E34BA404AB3F7CA5DC0E9C9F2" Name="$Resources:CuVi,ct_customervisitor_title;" Group="Custom Content Types" Description="$Resources:CuVi,ct_customervisitor_desc;" Inherits="FALSE" Version="0">
        <!-- Only reference with id, other properties coming from content type so no need to add additional properties -->
        <FieldRefs>          
          <FieldRef ID="{8A907E22-C36D-43C0-B541-6B8F8FBFBC0F}" />
          <FieldRef ID="{9c535734-2c4f-4259-8871-32ed72236731}" />          
          <FieldRef ID="{305ce425-9875-4604-8afc-39d79b779e72}" />          
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <!-- Why are all properties are needed? This is a senseless code duplication, why don't take it from Site Column Definition? -->
      <Field ID="{8A907E22-C36D-43C0-B541-6B8F8FBFBC0F}" Name="Customer" DisplayName="$Resources:CuVi,sc_customer;" Type="Text" Required="TRUE" Group="Customer Visitor Site Columns"></Field>
      <Field ID="{9c535734-2c4f-4259-8871-32ed72236731}" Name="Brand" DisplayName="$Resources:CuVi,sc_brand;" Required="TRUE" Type="Note" RichText="False" NumLines="4" Group="Customer Visitor Site Columns"></Field>      
      <Field ID="{305ce425-9875-4604-8afc-39d79b779e72}" Name="ContactPeople" DisplayName="$Resources:CuVi,sc_contactpeople;" BaseType="Text" Type="UserMulti" Sealed="TRUE" List="UserInfo" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" Group="Customer Visitor Site Columns"></Field>      
    </Fields>
    <Views>[...]</Views>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

I was successful on removing all additional properties from the FieldRefs, because the ID is enough to take all attributes from content type.

But in the Fields section, all attributes like Name, Type, etc are required.
So we have an **exact copy** of all attributes , which **I've already defined in the Site Column definition**.

Why do we need the attributes there?
Are there any way to achieve **lesser code** with **better maintaineable code** (without duplicate column attributes)?